# Can I open a psd file with Sumopaint?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[Sumopaint](http://www.sumopaint.com/www/) is an online photoshop like web-based utility, I am trying to open a psd file with the free online version but it does not open.

Can we open a psd file with Sumopaint, if yes how?

Comment: Hey coding crow, I don't think we need a tag for Sumopaint since this is the first question we've seen asking for Sumopaint support. As Kurt suggested, you'd probably be better off contacting their [support](http://support.sumoing.com/). If you do get it working, post it as an answer here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sumopaint (the free online version) supports PNG, GIF and JPG, plus a native format called SUMO which is analogous to PSD, and that's it. I've no idea if the pay-for versions offer more options.

http://support.sumopaint.com/customer/portal/articles/356737-images-and-formats